# Mysql query to select the second and third highest value and last entry in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

I need to select code for 2 and 3 Highest value from the last entry.

```
SNO  Userid  Price

1    1004   10
2    1002   20
3    1001   300
4    1003   700
5    1002   80
6    1001   50
```

Now I need to select last entry price for 1001 , 1002 , 1003, 1004.

**Result :**

```
1001 - 50, 1002 - 80, 1003 -700, 1004 -10.
```

The second highest value is  80 user 1002 
The third highest value is 50 user 1001

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from price order by price desc limit 2,1
union
select * from price order by price asc limit 1
```

as far as i understood you want second,third highest and least min value.

Comment: Thanks. User last place the bid value only needs to select. Ex User A = 100, User B = 200, User A = 300 , User C = 300 , User A 20, User B 10. Now need to select User A price = 20 and user B= 10. User C = 300. And than get 2 and 3 high value ?

Answer (score 1):

Mmm , not sure I understood but try this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM YourTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable s
                 WHERE t.userid = s.userid
                   AND s.sno > t.sno)
ORDER BY t.price DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Thanks.  User last place the bid value only needs to select.  Ex User A = 100, User B = 200, User A = 300 ,   User C = 300 ,  User A 20, User B 10.    Now need to select User A price = 20 and user B= 10. User C = 300.  And than get 2 and 3 high value ?

Answer (score 1):

Sample query :

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Price LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1 DESC
```

If I understand your problem !

Comment: Yes, Understood.  Your Ans is right for select the 2 and 3 high value. But the user last place the bid value only needs to select.  Ex User A = 100, User B = 200, User A = 300 ,   User C = 300 ,  User A 20, User B 10.    Now need to select User A price = 20 and user B= 10. User C = 300.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you very well ! would you like have a list with 3 - 1 latest rows inserted order by high value ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by giving a row number based on the group by `Userid` and descending order of `SNO`.

**Query**

```
select t.`SNO`, t.`Userid`, t.`Price` from(
  select `SNO`, `Userid`, `Price`, (
    case Userid when @curA 
    then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
    else @curRow := 1 and @curA := `Userid` end 
  ) as `rn`
  from `your_table_name` t, 
  (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r 
  order by `Userid`, `SNO` desc
)t
where t.`rn` = 1;
```